# Django template extending itself, maximum recursion depth exceeded when trying to extend the Django admin templates

Tags: python, django, templates

I am following [these instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) and I am stuck with a runtime error :

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I think the problem comes from the fact that I create and endless template look up.

More specifically, I copied the `base_site.html` from `contrib/admin/templates/admin` to my django project under `templates/admin`. Following the instructions, the project templates directory is referenced in `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and I am sure that `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` is set in such a way that django tries first to find the templates in the directories from `TEMPLATE_DIRS`. It is only when it fails to find the requested template in `TEMPLATE_DIRS` that it will search in the django system files.

However, the code of my personal admin template is

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'My Site Title - administration' %}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

and of course the `extends` statement is there because I want to extend the `base_site.html` from django. But because the first template loader used is `django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader`, and since my custom file has the same name as the django default file (i.e., "base_site.html"), I guess the loader is looping on my custom file over and over and ultimately raises the runtime error described above.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that simply consists of completely overriding `base_site.html`.

Instead of extending `base_site.html`, I just copied the code of `contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html` into my own `base_site.html` and changed the relevant fields. So I am actually extending `base.html` instead of `base_site.html` and the name conflict does not appear anymore.

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'My-Custom-Site site admin' %}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'My-Custom-Site site administration' %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

The drawback is that there is more code than it is required, but I am satisfied with this solution.